# How can I add tools in a tab of an Extjs TabPanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

How can I add the buttons (tools) in the header of each tab, in a TabControl?

I just could add tools in the TabPanel, but I want to add in the tabs.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek9sX.jpg)

I also tried this, but no success:

```
      var lTabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      renderTo: document.body,
      items: [{
          title: 'Home',
          html: 'Home',
          itemId: 'home'
      }, {
          title: 'Users',
          html: 'Users',
          itemId: 'users',
          hidden: true
      }, {
          title      : 'Tickets',
          html       : 'Tickets',
          itemId     : 'tickets',
          tools:[{
            type:'gear',
            tooltip: 'Options',
            handler: function(event, toolEl, panel){
                // Some code.
            }
          }]

      }]
  });
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite tough actually.

If you check their source code, `Ext.tab.Panel` is in fact using Card Layout and for each tab, they used `Ext.tab.Tab` to do the tab buttons.

Then if you check the source code of `Ext.tab.Tab`, it's in fact extending `Ext.button.Button`, which is just a modified button.

So if you need to add tools, I afraid the best way is to extend `Ext.tab.Tab` and write your own tab buttons. You might want to check out how they create `closeable` buttons in line **233** of `/src/tab/Tab.js`.

(Ext-4.0.2a)

Cheers

**EDIT**

So we know `Ext.tab.Tab` is extending `Ext.button.Button`, we can make use of this fact, and I have came out with this solution, check this out at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uBxqY/4/

Basically, I have extended `Ext.tab.Tab`, and modified the buttonWrapper class so to have the arrow css added. Nothing fancy, everything work out of the box.

Also I have overrided the `onClick` function so the menu won't be expanded when the user click on the tab itself. A little bit dirty, but it works (borrowed `prototype.onClick` from `Ext.button.Split`.

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/uBxqY/4/, or source:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.tab.Tab', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Tab',
    alias: 'widget.ux.menutab',
    requires: [
        //We just need the onClick from Split button
        'Ext.button.Split'
    ],

    /**
     * Menu align, if you need to hack the menu alignment
     */
    menuAlign: 'tl-bl?',

    constructor: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        //Kind of harsh, we need the click action from
        //split button instead.
        //Or if you preferred, you can always override this
        //function and write your own handler.
        this.onClick = Ext.button.Split.prototype.onClick;
    },


    /**
     * Hack the default css class and add
     * some resonable padding so to make it looks
     * great :)
     */
    onRender: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        //We change the button wrap class here! (HACK!)
        this.btnWrap.replaceCls('x-tab-arrow x-tab-arrow-right',
                               'x-btn-split x-btn-split-right')
                    .setStyle('padding-right', '20px !important');
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    style: 'margin:10px;',
    defaults: {
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px;'
    },
    plain: true,
    items: [{
        title: 'Split Tab',

        //tabConfig is taken up during tab formation
        tabConfig: {
            //We use our own custom tab!
            xtype: 'ux.menutab',
            menu: [{
                text: 'Menu item 1'
            },{
                text: 'Menu item 2'
            }]
        },
        html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    },{
        title: 'Normal Tab',
        html: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Lionel!
So, if a tab is in fact extending Ext.button.Button, I can add a menu to it, right? like a normal button... What do you think?

If yes, could you give me an ideia about how to do this?
(I will start trying this).

Ps: To make clear, the idea was to add tools and then link a menu to it. If it's not possible to add tools, just a menu would be good too.

Comment: This is a great solution!
However, I'm using ext-4.0.0 and I put this in my app and the menu doesn't appear.

I tried with ext-4.0.2a and doesn't work too... But in jsFiddle is perfect. 
I will keep trying... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird. All I did is basic stuff and doesn't rely on any third party script (as proven in jsfiddle). It should work out of the box perfectly :)

Comment: Lionel,
Wasn't working because I was using **ext-all-debug.js** instead **ext-all.js**. Weird, isn't it?
Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing solution!
This is my way (based on yours):

```
Ext.define('CB.view.ux.TabMenu', {
  extend: 'Ext.tab.Tab',
  alias: 'widget.tabmenu',
  requires: [
    'Ext.button.Split'
  ],

  menuAlign: 'tl-bl?',

  constructor: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.onClick = Ext.button.Split.prototype.onClick;
  },

  onRender: function() {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.btnWrap.insertSibling({
      tag: 'a',
      cls: 'arrow-inside-tab',
      href: '#'
    }, 'after');

    this.btnWrap.addCls(['pdr10']);  //padding-right: 10px; to make some place for arrow

  }
});
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-inside-tab {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  top: 5px;
  right: 4px;
  background: url("../js/extjs/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/button/arrow.gif") 1px 0 no-repeat;
}
```